# Format the output of a batch when saving to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to save the output of a batch to a log file , i was able to save the output to

a log file , but the problem is that its appending i want to get it as it is in the window.

am attaching the images of the console below .Thanks in advance  .

```
The window of getting the output :
```

[image]

`And the log  file :` [image]

Its appending the contents , its not breaking the lines OR how to achieve that ?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you, from a command window, execute `type file.log`? It seems that you have a text file with only line feeds between lines, without carriage return and notepad does not handle it very well.

Comment: I dont understand ,Actually I use these , cd c:/wamp/www/myfolder and then git ls-files -m > D:/msysgit/log.txt , which  list the files , and I attached the log.txt above,And its text file not log file

Comment: In windows, text file lines ends with a pair of characters: a carriage return (0x0D) and line feed (0x0A). But some tools generate output without the carriage return, only the line feed character is included. And notepad does not handle this type of files very well. If, from console, you use `type d:\msysgit\log.txt` (correct the name) and the output is correct, this is your case. If not, then we need more information on how you are generating your log.

Comment: Hmm it appends a C before the file names

Comment: Use a Hex Viewer like `WinHex` and see what is inside the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git ls-files -m | find /v "" > "D:\msysgit\log.txt"
git ls-files -m | more       > "D:\msysgit\log.txt"
```

Any of the two previous commans will parse the output of `git` adding the missing carriage return (if this is your case) from the end of the lines before sending the output to the final file.

If you use the `more` version, tabs in the output will be replaced with a sequence of spaces.